# Cronjobs not working but same command works fine from command line

Tags: command-line, php, cron, php-cli

I’ve installed Mautic (email program). It needs 3 cronjobs to run properly.

- `php /var/www/mydomainname/htdocs/app/console mautic:segments:update`
- `php /var/www/mydomainname/htdocs/app/console mautic:campaigns:update`
- `php /var/www/mydomainname/htdocs/app/console mautic:campaigns:trigger`

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and am using PHP 7.0x.

When I do `sudo php /var/www/mydomainname/htdocs/app/console mautic:campaigns:trigger`, or any other of the 3 listed above, they work without problem. I get the correct output and it’s executed.

However, when I put the same commands in a crontab, nothing happens.

I’ve tried everything. In the root crontab, in the www-data crontab, in my user crontab, with absolute paths to the PHP7.0 command (in `/usr/bin/php7.0`). Even tried first changing to the `php` directory and whatnot.

For example:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php7.0 /var/www/mydomainname/htdocs/app/console mautic:segments:update
```

Or:

```
* * * * * sudo /usr/bin/php7.0 /var/www/mydomainname/htdocs/app/console mautic:segments:update
```

Or:

```
* * * * * cd /usr/bin sudo php7.0 /var/www/mydomainname/htdocs/app/console mautic:segments:update
```

Nothing does the trick when using crontab.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Your timespec doesn't appear to have the right number of fields. You can get more diagnostic information by grepping /var/log/syslog (or perhaps `journalctl -eu cron.service`).

Comment: @steeldriver Can you change that into an answer please? :)

Comment: Actually the timespec thing is my fault .. there are 5 stars there in reality ... I didn't copy paste it right into the post ...

Answer (score -3):

From **[Jens A. Koch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163786/jens-a-koch)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22744360/1038860)** to [CronJob not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22743548/cronjob-not-running) (by [ROB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2659766/rob)) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/):

> Here's a checklist guide to debug not running cronjobs:
>
> 1. Is the Cron daemon running?
>
>    - Run `ps ax | grep cron` and look for cron.
>    - Debian: `service cron start` or `service cron restart`
> 2. Is cron working?
>
>    - `* * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> /tmp/file`
>    - Syntax correct? See below.
>    - You obviously need to have write access to the file you are redirecting the output to. A unique file name in `/tmp` which does not
>        currently exist should always be writable.
> 3. Is the command working standalone?
>
>    - Check if the script has an error, by doing a dry run on the CLI
>    - when testing your command, test as the user whose crontab you are editing, which might not be your login or root
> 4. Can cron run your job?
>
>    - Check `/var/log/cron.log` or `/var/log/messages` for errors.
>    - Ubuntu: `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`
>    - Redhat: `/var/log/cron`
> 5. Check permissions
>
>    - set executable flag on the command: `chmod +x /var/www/app/cron/do-stuff.php`
>    - if you redirect the output of your command to a file, verify you have permission to write to that file/directory
> 6. Check paths
>
>    - check she-bangs / hashbangs line
>    - do not rely on environment variables like PATH, as their value will likely not be the same under cron as under an interactive session
> 7. Don't suppress output while debugging
>
>    - commonly used is this suppression: `30 1 * * * command > /dev/null 2>&1`
>    - re-enable the standard output or standard error message output by removing `>/dev/null 2>&1` altogether; or perhaps redirect to a file
>        in a location where you have write access: `>>cron.out 2>&1` will
>        append standard output and standard error to `cron.out` in the
>        invoking user's home directory.
>
> **Still not working? Yikes!**
>
> 1. Raise the cron debug level
>
>    - Debian
>
>      - in `/etc/default/cron`
>      - set `EXTRA_OPTS="-L 2"`
>      - `service cron restart`
>      - `tail -f /var/log/syslog` to see the scripts executed
>    - Ubuntu
>
>      - in `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`
>      - add or comment out line `cron.crit /var/log/cron.log`
>      - reload logger `sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog reload`
>      - re-run cron
>      - open `/var/log/cron.log` and look for detailed error output
>    - Reminder: deactivate log level, when you are done with debugging
> 2. Run cron and check log files again
>
> **Cronjob Syntax**
>
> ```
> # Minute  Hour  Day of Month      Month         Day of Week    User Command    
> # (0-59) (0-23)   (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec) (0-6 or Sun-Sat)  
>
>     0       2       *             *                *          root /usr/bin/find
> ```
>
> This syntax is **only** correct for the `root` user. Regular user
>   `crontab` syntax doesn't have the *User* field (regular users aren't
>   allowed to run code as any other user);
>
> ```
> # Minute  Hour  Day of Month      Month         Day of Week    Command    
> # (0-59) (0-23)   (1-31)    (1-12 or Jan-Dec) (0-6 or Sun-Sat)  
>
>     0       2       *             *                *          /usr/bin/find
> ```
>
> **Crontab Commands**
>
> 1. `crontab -l`
>
>    - Lists all the user's cron tasks.
> 2. `crontab -e`, for a specific user: `crontab -e -u agentsmith`
>
>    - Starts edit session of your crontab file.
>    - When you exit the editor, the modified crontab is installed automatically.
> 3. `crontab -r`
>
>    - Removes your crontab entry from the cron spooler, but not from crontab file.